# VB.NET add or subtract an integer value to a SQL Server value into a label when selecting a combobox item

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, if-statement, combobox, label

Following my previous question answered by @Andrew Morton, I have one more :)

Here is my whole code (not very long for now) :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql

Public Class Form1

    Sub PopulateCB()

        Dim connection As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True"

        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM liste_unités"
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connection),
                da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        ComboBoxC1L1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxC1L1.DisplayMember = "nom_unité"

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PopulateCB()

    End Sub


    Private Sub ComboBoxC1L1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim cb = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)

        If cb.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim val = DirectCast(cb.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row.Field(Of Integer)("cout_unité")

            If ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "ordinaire" Then
                LabelPointsC1L1.Text = val
            ElseIf ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "médiocre" Then
                LabelPointsC1L1.Text = val - 2
            ElseIf ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "élite" Then
                LabelPointsC1L1.Text = val + 2
            End If

            If cb.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim val2 = DirectCast(cb.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row.Field(Of String)("type_unité")
                LabelUnitType.Text = val2
            End If
        End If

        Try
            Dim totalC1L1 As Integer
            totalC1L1 = CInt(TextBoxC1L1.Text) * CInt(LabelPointsC1L1.Text)
            LabelTotalC1L1.Text = totalC1L1

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "ordinaire"
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxC1L1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxC1L1.TextChanged
        Try
            Dim totalC1L1 As Integer
            totalC1L1 = CInt(TextBoxC1L1.Text) * CInt(LabelPointsC1L1.Text)
            LabelTotalC1L1.Text = totalC1L1

        Catch ex As exception
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

[Here is the program interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjUtG.jpg)

[Here is the SQL table look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdC05.jpg)

[Here is the program interface when the Button has been clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv4W5.jpg)

Red Arrow ComboBox text is a DropDownStyle box with 3 possible text choices:

```
ordinaire,
élite,
médiocre
```

What I want to do: when changing the red arrow combobox text, the cout_unité label should change too with a "cout_unité -2" in case of "médiocre" ComboBox text, or "cout_unité +2" in case of "élite" ComboBox text or remain = to "cout_unité" if the selected text is "ordinaire".

And it should calculate this only once from the original "cout_unité" value in the table (in case of clicking 10 times on "ordinaire", it shouldn't subtract 10 * 2 to the "cout_unité" value, only 1 * 2)

I can do it in the ComboBoxC1L1 (see code) but I can't reproduce it with this red arrow combobox (probably because of the type of data into this combobox which are "strings", I don't know).

Many thanks :)

Comment: "probably because of the type of data into this combobox which are "strings", I don't know" - put a breakpoint on and find out?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict now and forever. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also for future projects Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults  Correct any errors it points out.

Comment: @Mary : Ok done. Thanks for this.                                                                        Dale K : Even if I pointed this out, I'd be unable to correct it. That's why I asked for some expertise.

Comment: Don't write empty Catch blocks. They swallow errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only a single `Handle`s clause, the following line is unnecessary. The `sender` can only be the `ComboBox` in the `Handles`.

```
Dim cb = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
```

If you set the `ValueMember` of the combo in the `PopulateCB` method, you can save a long line of code making the code more readable.

```
Dim val = DirectCast(cb.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row.Field(Of Integer)("cout_unité")
```

To:

```
Dim val = CInt(ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedValue)
```

We need the CInt since SelectedValue is an Object.

Don't assign the `DataSource` until after the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are set.

You are checking twice for `ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedIndex >= 0`.
Just include the unit type in the first `If`.

The user may not have to trigger the `SelectedIndexChanged` event if the correct value is already selected. Maybe a button click would be better.

```
Sub PopulateCB()
    Dim connection As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM liste_unités"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connection),
            da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    ComboBoxC1L1.DisplayMember = "nom_unité"
    ComboBoxC1L1.ValueMember = "cout_unité"
    ComboBoxC1L1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculateValue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateValue.Click
    If ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim val = CInt(ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedValue)
        If ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "ordinaire" Then
            LabelPointsC1L1.Text = val.ToString
        ElseIf ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "médiocre" Then
            LabelPointsC1L1.Text = (val - 2).ToString
        ElseIf ComboBoxQC1L1.Text = "élite" Then
            LabelPointsC1L1.Text = (val + 2).ToString
        End If
        Dim val2 = DirectCast(ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row.Field(Of String)("type_unité")
        LabelUnitType.Text = val2
    End If
    Dim totalC1L1 As Integer
    totalC1L1 = CInt(TextBoxC1L1.Text) * CInt(LabelPointsC1L1.Text)
    LabelTotalC1L1.Text = totalC1L1.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Mary for this instructive input ! I’ll test that ! Cheers !

Comment: Ok I've tested the code and I get 2 problems. First one is ComboBoxC1L1.ValueMember = "cout_unité" and Dim val = CInt(ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedValue).

In ComboBox C1L1, there is not the "cout_unité", only the "nom_unité". The "cout_unité" should appear in LabelPointsC1L1.

I've replaced the line Dim val = CInt(ComboBoxC1L1.SelectedValue) by  Dim val = CInt(LabelPointsC1L1.Text) and it's working.

But now, the second problem I face (I had this issue before) is : each time I click on "calculate", it make the whole process.

The idea is to calculate the +2/-2 only once from the table value.

Comment: Example : For a "5" value, the max and min should be 3 and 7. It should not calculate each time I click on Calculate. I don't know if it's clear :D